# How to gracefully restart a Celery worker after a task in it caused SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception?

Tags: python, celery

A have a problem with my server environment which makes my tasks sometimes hang.

Sometimes the tasks go on, when I restart the Celery worker(s).

I don't have time/skills for now to debug the issue, so I thought of a workaround to restart the workers if a `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` exception was raised (I have a soft limit of 1 hour set for my tasks).

The thing is that I want to restart the worker which is possibly running the task. I.e. I want the worker to finish his current task stuff (setting task result, etc.) then to be restarted BEFORE it takes/runs the next task from the queue.

Comment: not sure why you want to restart, the worker should keep running. Anyway what about using signals (task_failure or something?) - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-failure

Comment: I have to check if this signal handler is called for `SoftTimeLimitExceeded`, because it's a special exception. The worker will keep running, just after a restart to reset its environment.